# Making wrapper for atomic blocks in java

Tags: java, stm

I am trying to implement STM api in java using TL2. I have written the the lower level functions like ReadTx and WriteTx but unable to convert to higher level constructs using keywords like atomic. For example my current implementation works for the first snippet of code but as it is cumbersome I want to convert to second.

```
  void PushLeft(DQueue *q, int val) {
    QNode *qn = malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    qn->val = val;
    do {
      StartTx();
      QNode *leftSentinel = ReadTx(&(q->left));
      QNode *oldLeftNode = ReadTx(&(leftSentinel->right));
      WriteTx(&(qn->left), leftSentinel);
      WriteTx(&(qn->right), oldLeftNode);
      WriteTx(&(leftSentinel->right), qn);
      WriteTx(&(oldLeftNode->left), qn);
    } while (!CommitTx());
  }

void PushLeft(DQueue *q, int val) {
    QNode *qn = malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    qn->val = val;
    atomic {
      QNode *leftSentinel = q->left;
      QNode *oldLeftNode = leftSentinel->right;
      qn->left = leftSentinel;
      qn->right = oldLeftNode;
      leftSentinel->right = qn;
      oldLeftNode->left = qn;
 } }
```

How can I do this without changing syntax of language?